# Problem with django tests

Tags: django, django-testing

I have simple app in my project. This app works without any problem. I want to test it so I created some tests for it. But when i want to run test for it I receive App with label 'x' could not be found. Tests works for other apps.

what is the problem?

Comment: Do you have a models.py for this app?

Comment: I think I deleted it by mistake. Thanks for tip :) This is the solution

Comment: I thought that might be it. I'll add that as an answer. It would be awesome if you could mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure you have a models.py for your app.